# Help me identify this B-movie about plant-like aliens that crash land

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

About 12 years ago I was in Blockbuster and while looking for something different I ventured into the VHS section. I can't quite remember my selection vividly because that night I rented 4 VHS for £1 and grabbed this movie purely out of curiosity to make up the 4 titles.

The movie I'm looking for must be from the 80's from what I remember of the cover as it art style had that classic *Star Wars* pencil/painting look to it. To my recollection, the picture was of a scary looking alien chasing some humans with some cheesy line like "They're here and they're hungry" (that's not the actual quote, but had that B-movie taste). I also remember the alien on the cover was blatantly nothing to do with or looked anything like the aliens in the movie, which is not uncommon for movies that age.

The plot, was the classic aliens crash landing in a country area (maybe even a farm?), they were carried by a meteor or capsule, definitely not a ship. This might have been a seed or seeds, as I distinctly remember a discussion about them being plant-life forms.
The plot may have revolved around them being plants and laying seeds on a farm so they may spread while the group of heroes tried to stop this from happening etc. Their seeds may have even looked like normal crops and the farmers may have tried to protect these seeds from the heroes so they could sell these 'crops' for extra money as they didn't believe they were alien? This is about all I can remember.

There were only 3 actual aliens, and I seemed to be surprised at the fact each one was very unique looking and of a different race from each other. They showed no signs of higher thought other then the uncanny alien skill for hiding, stalking and killing, like 90% of other aliens from B-movies. I think one of them could only travel underground very fast and chased people, another one was a flying/hovering round/fat eyeball (like a deceiver) and was possibly hairy/fluffy? I cant remember anymore about the third one. They were very comical looking, not at all scary and definitely not visually plant like.

This looked like other movies and had same slasher/alien feel as *Attack of the Killer Tomatoes*, *Critters* and also *The Deadly Swarm*, if that is any help. I just love movies from around the 80's and would like to rediscover this as no one I know can remember ever watching it. I've googled it to death, checked countless Wiki lists on late 70's 80's and early 90's sci-fi, horror, cult movies but never had any luck. It is also possible like many other movies from these periods, that this film has multiple names and covers? I know I've personally bought a couple movies on DVD that have turned out to be the same movie (although these are mostly zombie movies).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an 80's style "The Day of the Triffids" remake: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids  The miniseries is too late (2009) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids_%282009_TV_series%29

Comment: Although these aliens had something to do with being plant-based life-forms to my recollection they were not visually anything that ressembled a plant. It was like an after thought of "why would 3 aliens hang around a farm...I know they're plants" sorta thing.

Comment: I was trying to remember the name of that one myself. At the end when they think everything's over there's this big roar and a giant clam like alien is inside of a mountain it's actually part of the mountain. WHAT IS THE NAME .....DANG!!

Comment: You seem to be confusing 2 movies though (but you did say you picked up 4 movies at once, so...). The plot & aliens do sound like *Seedpeople*. But that handdrawn *cover* seems like [The Deadly Spawn](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTA5ZjZhNDAtMDczZS00OWEwLTkwMzktNGZlNmNiOGYxYThmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_.jpg), whose tagline was indeed "They're Here And They're Hungry" (also "They Came To Earth To Feed On Human Flesh!", "They Fell From Space And They Were Hungry!" & "Mankind Vs. The Ultimate Eating Machine"). It also contains the ending the previous commenter was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

**[Seedpeople](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105347/?ref_=nv_sr_1) from 1992?**

This is an old post, but I saw it and couldn't resist. I think this is the one as it has 3 aliens, they're plant-based but don't look like it, one could fly and was 'hairy/fluffy', I think they arrive in a meteor and it is in the country. It was definitely B grade and went straight-to-video, and it had a painted cover.

[image]

**Trailer:**

Comment: They look like seeds, they talk like people?

Comment: LOL Full Moon made some real classics back in the day

Comment: "The root of all evil" cheesy tagline checks out.

Answer (score 6):

I think this may be ["Pod People"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pod_People) aka "Extra Terrestrial Visitors".  This was also parodied by Mystery Science Theater 3000.  There weren't three separate types of Alien in that film though, only two - the juvenile and the adult.  I do seem to remember the conversation about them being plant based though.

Comment: Just checked this out on google. Although its got a similar plot and utterly-amazingly-stupid looking aliens in, alas it is not the answer I'm seeking. Nice try though as I have never seen this movie before so must be quite rare (although I dont think its possible to forget them aliens lol).

Comment: Like a lot of these questions, it reveals how very similar many story plots really are, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah I think at the height of retro B-movies you could buy a 'fill in the blanks' pre-written script and bang out a movie inside a weekend pen-to-recorded. Man I love them though.